# BPMN: placeholder to go to the "upper" model

Tags: placeholder, bpmn

Is there a good practice of what to use as a placeholder/link to go to the process map from a BPMN process? The idea is that people start with the process map that is linked to detailed processes but I am looking for a user-friendly way to let them go back to the process map fast, without having to look for it in the menu. (Currently using ADONIS tool)

Comment: Do you ask in general or for a specific tool?

Comment: It's a general BPMN question, thanks!

Comment: Your idea is not clear: what is to be done with this placeholder? Give an example.

Comment: I have a company map with the high level processes (e.g. "marketing, communication, etc"). when I click on "marketing", I go to the BPMN model. When I am in the BPMN model, I want to have a placeholder to go back to the company map